# move_uploaded_file from sub-directory to sibling parent directory

Tags: php, file

I am having issues transferring an uploaded file with the class_upload library from the directory of the .php file to a sibling of the parent directory.

Here is the directory breakdown

**home/hosted_domain/public_html/en_shop/profile.php**  <--- this is where the php file that handles the upload is

**home/hosted_domain/public_html/shop/avatars/**    <--- this is where the uploaded file needs to get

this is what I have tried -

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user-avatar']['tmp_name'], "home/hosted_domain/public_html/zadomaigradinata.bg/avatars/$avatar");
```

I've also tried using the site's URL + the directory /avatars/ but that didnt work either.

So how should we move the uploaded file ?

Comment: `home/...` is the directory `home` *relative to your current directory!* If you mean the absolute path, you need to use `/home/...`. Otherwise perhaps `__DIR__ . '../..'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend the directory path with a `/`.  This tells the system that you want that explicit path.  Without it, `move_uploaded_file` is trying to move the file to `/home/hosted_domain/public_html/en_shop/home/hosted_domain/public_html/zadomaigradinata.bg/avatars/$avatar` which is not what you want.

Comment: sry, I didn't have any time to check your solution before. It works bro it's awesome!  I didn't know it mattered if the directory had a slash in front. Thanks for the info!